# How to use OmniFaces Ajax.updateColumn() or Ajax.updateRow() via p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I am attempting to use the Ajax.updateColumn() method of the OmniFaces 1.3 (SNAPSHOT) Ajax utility. More specifically, I want to replace the use p:ajax update=":pageContentPanel", which is an h:panelGroup (or p:outputPanel) which contains the following xhtml, with the use of Ajax.updateColumn(table, 1).

```
<h:dataTable id="dt_tripDates" style="width: 200px !important;"
             var="tripDate" value="#{pf_ordersController.tripDates}">

    <p:column style="text-align: right !important;">
        <h:outputText id="rowNumber" value="#{tripDate.rowNumber}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="text-align: center !important;">
        <p:calendar id="tripDate" value="#{tripDate.tripDate}"
                    size="16" label="Trip Date"
                    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true"
                    onchange="changeOthersOnDateChange(this);">
            <p:ajax partialSubmit="false" event="dateSelect"
                    listener="#{pf_ordersController.tripDateSelectedOnAddUsingTemplate}"
                    update=":pageContentPanel"/>
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </p:calendar>
    </p:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

In the bean, I have the following, which is referenced by p:ajax listener="...":

```
public void tripDateSelectedOnAddUsingTemplate(DateSelectEvent event) {
    DateTime dt, today = DateTime.now(),
             tripDateTime = new DateTime(event.getDate());
    String clientId = event.getComponent().getClientId();
    Integer pos = clientId.indexOf(":tripDate") - 1,
            rowNumber = Integer.valueOf(clientId.substring(clientId.lastIndexOf(":", pos) + 1, pos + 1));
    /*
     * clientId = orderAddUsingTemplateForm:dt_tripDates:0:tripDate
     * id = tripDate
     */
    /*
     * if tripDates in the list, that follow the argument tripDate in the list,
     * have today's Date, then set them to the argument
     */
    for (int i = rowNumber; i < nbrOfTripDates; i++) {
        tripDates.get(i).setTripDate(tripDateTime.toDate());
    }
    // OmniFaces Ajax utility to update UIData columns
    Ajax.updateColumn(tripDatesDataTable, 1);
}
```

While attempting to use Ajax.updateColumn(), I added "HtmlDataTable tripDatesDataTable" as an attribute to the bean.

The bean is JSF @SessionScoped managed bean. Please let me know how I can call Ajax.updateColumn() when p:ajax (belonging to p:calendar in xhtml above) is executed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that you've got to have a handle to the [`UIData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component somehow so that you can pass it to `Ajax#updateColumn()`. In your particular case, easiest way would be to get it by `event.getComponent()` with help of [`Components#getClosestParent()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html#getClosestParent%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Class%29).

```
UIData tripDatesDataTable = Components.getClosestParent(event.getComponent(), UIData.class);
// ...
Ajax.updateColumn(tripDatesDataTable, 1);
```

Note that you can also just get the row number this way without the need to break down the client ID.

```
int rowNumber = tripDatesDataTable.getRowIndex();
```

Comment: works perfectly! Another great BalusC answer/response and solution! Thank you.