# Unable to update p:datatable cell after ajax call on another cell's cellEdit event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

In my cell edit event in my backing bean, if the cell value is changed I want to update the value of another column as well of the datatable. The value is getting correctly set in my list object but is not getting reflected in my datatable. I tried updating using the datatable using RequestContext as well, but still the list is not getting refreshed. What am I doing wrong? Should I call any row event for this change?

### **Code snippet :**

**Bean**

```
@Named("editView")
@ViewScoped

public class EditTableView implements Serializable {


    private List<Cars> carList;
    private List<String> brands;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        brands = new ArrayList<String>();
        brands.add("BMW");
        brands.add( "Mercedes");
        brands.add("Volvo");
        brands.add("Audi");
        brands.add("Renault");
        brands.add("Fiat");
        brands.add("Volkswagen");
        brands.add("Honda");
        brands.add("Jaguar");
        brands.add( "Ford");
        brands.add("Maruti Suzuki");

        carList = new ArrayList<Cars>();
        modifiedList = new ArrayList<Cars>();
        Cars car =new Cars();
        car.setCarId(1);
        car.setBrand("BMW");
        car.setColor("Grey");
        car.setModelNumber("2323");
        car.setSelfDriven("Y");
        car.setYear("1980");
        car.setStatus("");

        carList.add(car);               
    }




    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {

        int rowIndex = event.getRowIndex();
        Cars car = null;
        LOGGER.info("Car Edited"+rowIndex);

        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        DataTable carTable = (DataTable)   event.getSource();
        String index = carTable.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        LOGGER.info(index);

        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            LOGGER.info("Cell Changed Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            car=carList.get(rowIndex);    
            carList.get(event.getRowIndex()).setStatus("Changed");      
            modifiedList.add(car);
        }
    }    
}
```

xhtml

```
<h:form id="cellEditForm">

    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{editView.carList}"
        editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">
        <f:facet name="header">Cell Editing</f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{editView.onCellEdit}"
            update=":cellEditForm:cars" />

        <p:column headerText="Id">
            #{car.carId}
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Model Name" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.modelNumber}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.modelNumber}"
                        style="width:96%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:96%" label="Year" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Brand" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.brand}" style="width:100%">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{editView.brands}" var="man"
                            itemLabel="#{man}" itemValue="#{man}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Self Driven" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.selfDriven}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inplace>
                        <p:inputText value="#{car.selfDriven}" />
                    </p:inplace>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.color}" style="width:96%" label="Color" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>


        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.status}" id="statusLabel"></h:outputText>

        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Comment: next time please format the code better.

Comment: try  update="cars" instead update=":cellEditForm:cars"

Comment: And that is different, why?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091742/how-to-use-omnifaces-ajax-updatecolumn-or-ajax-updaterow-via-pajax

Comment: @Kukeltje I actually require a solution in primefaces or core jsf library. I cannot incorporate Omnifaces in my project. Thanks for the solution though :)

Comment: Then download the OmniFaces source and paste the source of the Ajax util in your own source. And after that, shoot the one that forbids the one that tells you you cannot use OmniFaces. (Or tell his/her boss he/she is preventing you to work more optimally and require you to write custom code that could very easily be solved by incorporating OmniFaces) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I used jquery eventually. Got the index of the updated row and called jquery function from my bean.

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
String call = "updateCell(" + event.getRowIndex() + ")";
requestContext.execute(call);
```

Jquery code

```
function updateCell(i) {
   var index =  "cellEditForm:cars:"+i+":statusLabel";  
   document.getElementById(index).innerHTML="Changed";
}
```

Comment: This is not 'updating' it in a JSF way. It just replaces the content of the page with a static value. If you want to do it like this, at least also return the value of the property in the relevant bean.

Comment: and btw, this is updating a cell, not a row, so please correct the question then

Answer (score -1):

OmniFaces has a great util for this, called ['Ajax'](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax)

A StackOverflow post about this shows how to use it: [How to use OmniFaces Ajax.updateColumn() or Ajax.updateRow() via p:ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091742/how-to-use-omnifaces-ajax-updatecolumn-or-ajax-updaterow-via-pajax)

Comment: I accept downvotes if appropriate, but can the downvoter (or someone else) please state why this is not a good answer to the question as it stands now (besides the comment of the OP that OmniFaces cannot be used)

Answer (score -2):

Update form not table or put table in panel and update panel.

to be safe

```
<h:form id="cellEditForm">
<p:panel id="something" styleclass="pero">
   <p:dataTable id="cars

update="@(.pero)"
```

be sure to put id on panel because class update will  search for that id and use it. This solution is because i don't know rest of the code and it is one that will work on any code.

Comment: I tried with all the changes suggested above, but its not giving the desired result. On using `update=cars` ,clears the form and shows only the modified value on the form. I have now pasted my entire code for reference.

Comment: `String updatedIndex = carTable.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) + ":" + event.getRowIndex() +":statusLabel";
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(updatedIndex);`  is not updating the cell

Comment: So put stylclass to every element you wont to update. Principle is the same.